# How do you close a jQuery Simplemodal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, simplemodal

I want to close a Simplemodal window from a JavaScript function that gets called automatically after a form is submitted and the results recived (AJAX), using ASP.Net MVC. How do I close a jQuery Simplemodal?

I've opened it this way:

```
$("#popup").modal()
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Put the close class (simplemodal-close) on an element in your modal data and SimpleModal will automatically bind the close function to the click event on that element.

Taking the example above, you'd want:

```
<div id="foo" style="display:none">
  <p>Form HTML</p>
  <span class="simplemodal-close">Close</span>
</div>
```

2) When you want to close the dialog programatically, call:

```
$.modal.close();
```

HTH!

-Eric (SimpleModal author)

Comment: Where is CDN for css of simple modal? I've found only CDN for *.js of simple modal: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemodal/1.4.4/jquery.simplemodal.min.js

Answer (score 7):

Just call close.

```
$("#popup").close();
```

If you're doing it for an ajax completion you need to add a callback.  You may want to check for failure.

```
var foo = $("#popup").modal();

$.ajax({url:url, success:function(){
    foo.close();
}});
```

Answer (score 4):

If none of the above solutions work, you can also try to trigger the click event of the close button (so long as it is placed inside the popup element).

```
$( ".simplemodal-close" ).trigger( "click" );
```

or failing that, with Javascript.

```
document.getElementById('closeModalButton').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.modal.close();
```

or you can use following command

```
setTimeout('goto_previous_page()', 1000);
```