# Jquery Model dialog close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii-booster

How is it possible to force the jquery popup box to close only when CLOSE button is clicked?

Here is the code.

jQuery('#myModal').modal({'show':false});

**Now its also closing when clicking outside of the Model Box.**

Extension : http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/modals/view/modal.html

Comment: duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935573/how-do-you-close-a-jquery-simplemodal][1]

    $.modal.close();


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935573/how-do-you-close-a-jquery-simplemodal

Comment: i am asking for a way to stop closing the model when cling outside of the window.

Comment: *"jquery popup box"* is very vague. Please link to the exact plugin you're using. does `yii-booster` create the popup..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `backdrop="static"` that should force the modal to stay open

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
```

[Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)